# Touchpad not recognized on linux (ASUS R751LB)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, touchpad, asus

I have just bought a brand new laptop. Unfortunately, touchpad doesn't work on any linux distribution (tried mint Ubuntu 12.04, Ubuntu 14.04, Mint 14, Mint 16, also Mint 16 with recent 3.13.5 kernel).

`xinput list` returns:

```
> Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
> ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                  id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

`synclient -l` returns:

> Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?

`dmesg | grep -i mouse` returns:

> [    1.024913] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice

Touchpad works completely under Windows, even in Windows boot instalation menu.

USB mouse works fine under linux.

Seems like Linux just doesn't see any touchpad device in my computer. It's ASUS R751LB (more popular name: Asus X750). I already searched almost whole internet and seems like not many people has such an issue as me.

Anybody has any ideas how to fix it?

BTW. My keyboard fn key also doesn't work. However, I do care about fixing touchpad mostly. I don't think fixing fn key would fix touchpad, even if I have a touchpad toggle on/off button here - even it was turned off, it should be visible by drivers.

### EDIT

Output for `lshw`:

```
slimakbook
    description: Desktop Computer
    product: X750LB (ASUS-NotebookSKU)
    vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    version: 1.0
    serial: E1N0CV213307025
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.8 dmi-2.7 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=desktop family=U sku=ASUS-NotebookSKU uuid=D07C4055-317C-F581-3DAD-D850E6DF4EDE
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: X750LB
       vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
       physical id: 0
       version: 1.0
       serial: BSN12345678901234567
       slot: To be filled by O.E.M.
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: 210
          date: 12/27/2013
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 6080KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200U CPU @ 1.60GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 3d
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200U CPU @ 1.60GHz
          slot: SOCKET 0
          size: 1600MHz
          capacity: 3800MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4
        *-cache:0
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 3e
             slot: CPU Internal L2
             size: 512KiB
             capacity: 512KiB
             capabilities: internal write-back unified
        *-cache:1
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 3f
             slot: CPU Internal L1
             size: 128KiB
             capacity: 128KiB
             capabilities: internal write-back
        *-cache:2
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: 40
             slot: CPU Internal L3
             size: 3MiB
             capacity: 3MiB
             capabilities: internal write-back unified
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 41
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 8GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
             product: ASU16D3LS1KBG/4G
             vendor: Kingston
             physical id: 0
             serial: C028E3F9
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM [empty]
             product: [Empty]
             vendor: [Empty]
             physical id: 1
             serial: [Empty]
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
        *-bank:2
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
             product: 8KTF51264HZ-1G6E1
             vendor: Micron
             physical id: 2
             serial: E88DD71D
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:3
             description: DIMM [empty]
             product: [Empty]
             vendor: [Empty]
             physical id: 3
             serial: [Empty]
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 09
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:63 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
        *-multimedia:0
             description: Audio device
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:66 memory:f7a14000-f7a17fff
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:60 memory:f7a00000-f7a0ffff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: Lynx Point-LP HECI #0
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:65 memory:f7a1d000-f7a1d01f
        *-multimedia:1
             description: Audio device
             product: Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:67 memory:f7a10000-f7a13fff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: e4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:56 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:cf200000-cf3fffff ioport:cf400000(size=2097152)
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
             version: e4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:57 memory:f7900000-f79fffff
           *-network UNCLAIMED
                description: Network controller
                product: MEDIATEK Corp.
                vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                version: 00
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: memory:f7900000-f79fffff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: e4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:58 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:f7800000-f78fffff ioport:f2100000(size=1048576)
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: eth0
                version: 0c
                serial: d8:50:e6:df:4e:de
                size: 1Gbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=10.42.0.26 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
                resources: irq:62 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7800000-f7800fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 5
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.4
             version: e4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:59 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:f6000000-f70fffff ioport:e0000000(size=301989888)
           *-display
                description: 3D controller
                product: GK208M [GeForce GT 740M]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
                resources: irq:64 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: Lynx Point-LP USB EHCI #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:f7a1b000-f7a1b3ff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:61 ioport:f0b0(size=8) ioport:f0a0(size=4) ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f060(size=32) memory:f7a1a000-f7a1a7ff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f7a19000-f7a190ff ioport:f040(size=32)
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 1
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: KINGSTON SV300S3
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 521A
             serial: 50026B723C0D1BA2
             size: 111GiB (120GB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=aec85945-a3a5-46b1-a4be-52e803e4be5a sectorsize=512
           *-volume:0
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: mkdosfs
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                logical name: /boot/efi
                version: FAT32
                serial: 9280-baba
                size: 486MiB
                capacity: 486MiB
                capabilities: boot fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro state=mounted
           *-volume:1
                description: EFI partition
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                logical name: /boot
                version: 1.0
                serial: c9337ee9-2364-4e17-a0ab-680713f9fdfa
                size: 244MiB
                capabilities: extended_attributes ext2 initialized
                configuration: filesystem=ext2 lastmountpoint=/boot modified=2014-03-03 16:46:30 mount.fstype=ext2 mount.options=rw,relatime mounted=2014-03-03 16:46:30 state=mounted
           *-volume:2
                description: LVM Physical Volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                serial: DeUlFh-ianG-W9G1-2hTn-KQ7h-4RtH-vY6dMF
                size: 111GiB
                capabilities: multi lvm2
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi2
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: DVD-RAM UJ8DB S
             vendor: MATSHITA
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: R.00
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
     *-scsi:2
          physical id: 3
          bus info: usb@1:1.4
          logical name: scsi3
          capabilities: emulated scsi-host
          configuration: driver=usb-storage
        *-disk
             description: SCSI Disk
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdb
             size: 3824MiB (4009MB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: sectorsize=512 signature=befd22a5
           *-volume
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: MSDOS5.0
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sdb1
                logical name: /media/slimak/SLIMAKDRIVE
                version: FAT32
                serial: 1895-ed64
                size: 3823MiB
                capacity: 3823MiB
                capabilities: primary bootable fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro state=mounted
     *-scsi:3
          physical id: 4
          bus info: usb@1:1.5
          logical name: scsi4
          capabilities: emulated scsi-host
          configuration: driver=usb-storage
        *-disk
             description: SCSI Disk
             product: Card  Reader
             vendor: Multiple
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdc
             version: 1.00
             serial: AU6485
             capabilities: removable
             configuration: ansiversion=4 sectorsize=512
           *-medium
                physical id: 0
                logical name: /dev/sdc
  *-power UNCLAIMED
       description: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       product: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       vendor: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       physical id: 1
       version: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       capacity: 32768mWh
```

Comment: We might be able to help if we can figure out the exact touchpad model. Try `lshw` or `hwinfo` (both should be available in the Ubuntu repositories, run them with `sudo`). Otherwise, check in Windows, presumably it will be listed there.

Comment: It works even under Windows XP. Windows shows "Unknown device model", but when going into device details, its: `ACPI\ETD0108\4&A341153&0` and uses `drivers\i8042prt.sys` driver.

Comment: Did you try `lshw` or `hwinfo`?

Comment: Here's a lshw output: http://pastebin.com/ACMmcYJD .

Comment: I have this exact problem on a very similar laptop model (ASUS X750LA, Linux Mint 16 (kernel 3.11.0-18-generic). Touchpad works fine in Windows 8 but Linux does not think it even exists. I get similar output as the OP from `xinput list`, `synclient -l`, `dmesg | grep -I mouse`, and `lshw`, with no mention of the touchpad that I can see. According to Windows 8, the driver name is msmouse.inf and the driver is ACPI\ETD0108\4&340f64ca&0 (driver date is 06/21/2006). Any idea what's wrong, anyone?

Comment: Output from the commands mentioned: http://pastebin.com/azCDYW8m

Comment: I haven't found any solution yet and I'm living without a touchpad still. Let me now if you find something!

Comment: You can try all the solutions found in [Asus touchpad not detected under Ubuntu Linux](http://cksum.blogspot.com/2014/06/asus-touchpad-not-detected-under-ubuntu.html) and see if this works for you. It didn't for me unfortunately.

Comment: same problem. [This link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1314198/comments/31) worked like a charm!