# Touchpad recognized as PS/2 mouse and not working (Kernel 3.14.3-2)

Tags: arch-linux, touchpad, asus

On an ASUS r510l or x550l laptop the touchpad is not working. I run Arch Linux, with kernel 3.14.3-2, but I also tried it in Ubuntu 12.04, Ubuntu 14.04, Debian Jessie and Fedora. This is what I get from `xinput`:

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse                 id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB_PS2 Optical Mouse                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

It gets recognized as a PS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse, and the `psmouse` module is loaded, but the touchpad doesn't work, `dmesg` keeps showing the same message over and over:

```
psmouse serio4: Failed to enable mouse on isa0060/serio4
```

And using `hwinfo` it also appears as a mouse:

```
$ hwinfo
PS/2 00.0: 10500 PS/2 Mouse
  [Created at input.249]
  Unique ID: AH6Q.U5GX9Ignjc0
  Hardware Class: mouse
  Model: "PS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse"
  Vendor: 0x0002 
  Device: 0x0001 "PS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse"
  Compatible to: int 0x0210 0x0003
  Device File: /dev/input/mice (/dev/input/mouse1)
  Device Files: /dev/input/mice, /dev/input/mouse1, /dev/input/event15, /dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-4-event-mouse, /dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-4-mouse
  Device Number: char 13:63 (char 13:33)
  Driver Info #0:
    Buttons: 3
    Wheels: 0
    XFree86 Protocol: explorerps/2
    GPM Protocol: exps2
    Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
```

I tried several things, like installing the ALPSv7 module or an elantech module, and nothing worked. I posted this on the Arch forum (https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=181048) and so far I haven't got any  information. I found other people having a similar problem with another ASUS model here:
[Touchpad not recognized on linux (ASUS R751LB)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117940/touchpad-not-recognized-on-linux-asus-r751lb)

But I'm not sure if it is related, since mine gets recognized (only as a mouse).

EDIT: I have updated to kernel 3.14.6 and it is still not solved. If someone knows an easy guide to kernel drivers I can try to take a further look.

Seems a generalized bug of various Asus models:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1325881

But so far there isn't a solution.

Comment: @raphaelh notes that "Hans de Goede is currently taking care of debugging this problem on [Redhat's bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1110011).

Comment: Thanks @raphaelh, I was checking the thread and it seems they made some progress, I'm looking forward to try the patched kernel soon (as I have Arch Linux I will have to wait till they update the repos there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a workaround given here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1314198/comments/31

no full support of the touchpad, but at least... go ahead & see, if it'll work for you as well!

Comment: In the future, it's a good idea to add the important bits from a link if it doesn't take too much space to do so (and it would only be a couple of lines for this case).

Comment: Thank you! The workaround worked for me, at least I can use the touchpad in the meanwhile. Anyway, if someone has some information about how could I help to debug or fix this, I'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem with an ASUS K551L XO301H I acquired recently.  Passing the parameter `psmouse.proto=bare` to the kernel boot line fixed it for me.

Comment: In the future, make your posts to Stack Exchange in English.  See [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/).